# App Settings: How to update environment settings during deployment?

Tags: android, ios, xamarin

I'm creating a Xamarin (iOS and Android) application that will run in several environments: dev, QA, internal, production, etc. Each environment will have a unique environment setup configuration, e.g. each will have it's own "base url" ("dev.example.com", "prod.example.com").

I have done a good amount of web development but I'm new to mobile. If I was creating a web app I would put these variables in a web.config and the deploy system would update the file when the app was deployed to each environment. Similarly, in the Xamarin app, I have created a "config.json" file in the shared project to store these environment variables.

```
{
  "BaseUrl": "https://dev.example.com",
  "AppId": "65431651235136513513651"
}
```

The [Xamarin documentation](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/working-with/files/#Loading_Files_Embedded_as_Resources) encourages me to add this file as an embedded resource. However, if I go this route I assume that I will have to rebuild the app each time I deploy to a new environment. While this is certainly an option, it seems less than optimal. I would prefer to have the app load the file directly so that I can just reuse the build artifacts and update the file when I deploy. Will this be too challenging to be worth the effort? If not, how would I go about doing this?

Comment: Another approach is compiler directives, we're using this successfully for multiple apps. If interested, I'll post an answer that goes that way.

Comment: @MarkLarter Cool idea, but I don't think it fits what I'm looking for. In addition to requiring a build for each environment it means that the values have to be embedded in the source. With a config file, the build pipeline can make a simple substitution on the fly.

Comment: We use a single (Jenkins) build definition, just pass appropriate build variables, but yes these values are in source code. But then again, the config.json is "source" too, depending on your perspective. There are certainly a few ways to do this, but none of them as easy as a web app. :-)